# Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

i just want to get 50 data in my page but i can get orderBy does not exist error message here is my query which i am wrote on blade file..i am getting this error when i put paginate

```php
$currentMonth = date('m');
$currentyear = date('Y');
$query = Modules\Leads\Entities\Lead::whereNull('archived_at')
    ->where('stage_id', $card->id)
    ->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',[$currentMonth])
    ->whereRaw('YEAR(created_at) = ?',[$currentyear])
    ->with(['agent:id,username,name'])
    ->paginate(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including `orderBy()` in your query. Something like:

```php
$query = Modules\Leads\Entities\Lead::whereNull('archived_at')
    ->where('stage_id', $card->id)
    ->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',[$currentMonth])
    ->whereRaw('YEAR(created_at) = ?',[$currentyear])
    ->with(['agent:id,username,name'])
    ->orderBy('fieldToOrderBy', 'desc')
    ->paginate(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `orderBy()` clause in your query. Do it like

```
$query = Modules\Leads\Entities\Lead::whereNull('archived_at')
    ->where('stage_id', $card->id)
    ->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',[$currentMonth])
    ->whereRaw('YEAR(created_at) = ?',[$currentyear])
    ->with(['agent:id,username,name'])
    ->orderBy('fieldToSort', 'desc')
    ->paginate(50);
```

I presume you are expecting data in descending order.